# Can I select a element behind a transparent image?

Tags: html, css, transparent

I want to deselect a transparent image to select the element behind it, without use the `propriety z-index`, please help me ! Here the [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/marcellokabora/h2QkR/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just bring the input to the front by changing it's order?

HTML:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" name="" value="SELECT ME PLEASE !"/>
<div id="menulogo"><img src="http://www.marcellokabora.com/web/wokomoko/img/menulogo.png"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #myinput{
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 260px;
    font-size: 20px;
}​
​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bW52t/

Else, use `pointer-events` to make the element "click-through"

HTML:

```
<div id="menulogo"><img src="http://www.marcellokabora.com/web/wokomoko/img/menulogo.png"/></div>
<input id="myinput" type="text" name="" value="SELECT ME PLEASE !"/>

​
```

CSS:

```
#menulogo,#menulogo  img{
    pointer-events: none;
}
#myinput{
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 260px;
    font-size: 20px;
}​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2m4Tx/

Comment: pointer-events !! great U win ! thanks very musch ! 10000 point.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have the z-index set I don't think there's a way to access the overlapped by that transparent image elements. Of course you could write a short JS that will change the z-index value of the image, or will shortly hide it, etc. but without editing this property I think it's rather impossible..

Cheers!

Comment: look the Jsfiddle example on top !

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one. You will have problems with older IE browsers when trying to set the index of an image even when using z-index. It seems, browsers like IE7 disregard the index of an image even when it's behind an input box (for instance). 
Your best bet is to set the image as a background image of a div in css and have both elements with absolute position.

```
<div style="position:absolute; background: url(images/myimage.jpg) no-repeat"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left : 15px">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: look the Jsfiddle example on top !

Comment: No It cant do ! try the jsfiddle demo!